# No objection letter from job for visitor visa required or not?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

For my father visitor visa application we are submitting 
employment letter
payslips and bank statement
do we need to submit holiday NOC ( no objection letter) for holidays  from Employer or unnescasary ?

Answer (score 1):

The Visit guidance suggests that confirmation of employment should be provided but does not specifically mention holiday NOC https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf

The guidance isn’t intended to be a definitive list of all possible supporting documents. Each applicant’s circumstances are different, so I would include it if you have it.